# IntelliJ sometimes does not respect breakpoints

Tags: intellij-idea, breakpoints

I have the following code:

```
/*01*/ final BlockingQueue<CsvFileRow> allRows = new LinkedBlockingQueue<CsvFileRow>();
/*02*/ ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
/*03*/ Callable<Void> producer = new Callable<Void>() {
/*04*/   @Override
/*05*/   public Void call() throws Exception {
/*06*/     System.out.println("Before producer");
/*07*/     produceDataRows(allRows);
/*08*/     System.out.println(" After producer");
/*09*/     return null;
/*10*/   }
/*11*/ };
/*12*/ Callable<Void> consumer = new Callable<Void>() {
/*13*/   @Override
/*14*/   public Void call() throws Exception {
/*15*/     System.out.println("Before consumer");
/*16*/     consumeDataRows(allRows);
/*17*/     System.out.println(" After consumer");
/*18*/     return null;
/*19*/   }
/*20*/ };
/*21*/ exec.submit(producer);
/*22*/ exec.submit(consumer);
/*23*/ exec.shutdown();
/*24*/ exec.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.DAYS);
/*25*/ assert Boolean.TRUE;
```

I have breakpoints on lines 7, 16, 21 and 25. Running the code stops on the breakpoints 21,7 and then 25 - the breakpoint 16 is skipped! But, the code has been executed, see the output:

```
Before producer
Before consumer
 After consumer
 After producer
```

Now, if I remove the breakpoint 7, then the debugger stops on the breakpoints 21,16 and then 25.

This is an extremely annoying issue. In fact, there are other scenarios where I have noticed that IntelliJ ignores the breakpoints, which is very disturbing.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not necessarily IDEA bug, in some cases Java Debugger API doesn't report breakpoint hits, so it could be Java bug as well. Did you try to rebuild the project ensuring that debug info is enabled with the more recent Java version? If you have an isolated project that can reproduce this problem consistently, please submit it at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA.

Comment: Same issue +3 years latters....

Comment: Are you running the program via Intellij or are you attaching the Intellij Debugger to a remote process (ex: WebApp running in Tomcat)?